# How do I pass primary key from url to function based view in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I have a function based view as:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def hotel_detail(request, pk):
    # Lots of code
```

and I'm using this URL pattern:

```
url(r'^hotel/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', api.hotel_detail)
```

but it's not working

view:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def hotel_detail(request, pk):
    # Retrieve, update or delete a Hotel instance.
    try:
        hotel = models.Hotel.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except models.Hotel.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = serializers.HotelSerializer(hotel)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = serializers.HotelSerializer(hotel, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        hotel.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Im not receiving any error message.

Comment: Add `views.py` and post the error.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: I'm not receiving any error message.

Comment: in urly.py:  api.hotel_detail or views.hotel_detail ?

Comment: I have created views in api.py file.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try with **Named groups**

In your **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
         url(r'^hotel/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', api.hotel_detail name="hotel_details"),
]
```

If you want know more refer the doc [Named groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#named-groups)